# TypeError when using snscrape

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm following a tutorial on YouTube that shows how to get recent tweets from a user. However I run into a

`TypeError: TwitterUserScraper.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

Below is the code.

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as twitterScraper

scraper = twitterScraper.TwitterUserScraper("elonmusk", False)

for i, tweet in enumerate(scraper.get_items()):
    if i > 2:
        break
print(f"{i} content: {tweet.content}")
```

I'm not really sure how I can fix this since I have copied the code straight from the video. Thanks for the help.